# How to delete this file with owner/group/access unkown

Tags: shell

Somehow the file `id_rsa` changes to what it looks like as blow:

`> ll id_rsa
?--------- ? ?    ?      ?            ? id_rsa`

I could not delete it, `chmod` or `chown` it.

Could anyone figure out a way to delete it, or fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Either you don't have access(x) permission to the directory containing the file (only read permission), or the file system is broken.

Comment: Try to see if there is some file attributes with `lsattr id_rsa`.

Comment: may be try using this command to remove that file `rm -rf "?--------- ? ?    ?      ?            ? id_rsa"`   Note: Double quotes is important while running this command. @ilkkachu

Comment: Use this command to see the get file access control lists `getfacl "?--------- ? ?    ?      ?            ? id_rsa"` @ilkkachu